# deep Copy shallow Copy Matlab structs/struct fields

Tags: matlab, data-structures, struct, deep-copy, shallow-copy

Hi i want to  change the struct `mySTruct` after i did some subtractions with struct fields. How can i copy my new structs into `mySTruct` without addressing the path with( `mySTruct.KMZ`......)
I need to Copy the results into a cell in depth 3 of `mySTruct` (`mySTruct.KMZ.Lstgn.Abkm`)
The important part of my code is this calculation

```
currentFile = mySTruct .(subsref(fieldnames(mySTruct ),substruct('{}',{k})));
 for idx = 2 : cellRowSize
                display(idx)     
                resForLstg(idx,1) = table(currentEnergie(idx,2)-currentEnergie(idx-1,2));  
                %Res for column 2
                resForLstg(idx,2) = table(currentEnergie(idx,3)-currentEnergie(idx-1,3));        
                %Res for column 3

currentFile.Lstg.(subsref(fieldnames(currentFile.Energie),substruct('{}',{i}))) = resForLstg;
```

The problem is that `currentFile` is a new  independent struct and has nothing  in common with the Struct `mySTruct` .
The last row of my code dosent change `mySTruct`

Comment: In MATLAB if you want to chagne the value of sometihng, you need to simple express it literally.  So if you want to change the old struct, put it in the left hand side of an equal sign.

Comment: ok thanks but is there any way i cann addrass the struct i want. Because my struct has 5 struct fields and these struct field have also 3-6 structs

Comment: my biggest suggestion is to find a reasonable way of storing the data that does not contain 10 subfields. That sounds horrendous to work with.

Comment: MATLAB doesn't do references. You need to do `mySTruct .(subsref(fieldnames(mySTruct ),substruct('{}',{k}))).Lstg.(subsref(fieldnames(currentFile.Energie),substruct('{}',{i}))) = resForLstg;`, which, as Ander suggested, is horrendous. You seem to want to index into a struct using indices. Why not use a cell array instead? `myCell{k,i}`.

Comment: ok thank you this was verry helpfull